# CQ / AEM - clientLibs and Absolute URLs

Tags: adobe, aem

So We are building a website using AEM6 and Sightly.  There is a 2nd site supported by a third party for the ticketing on a different domain.

The 2nd site want to consume our header, footer and head tags to take our styling and layout into their own html include. Easily done with a sling selector; /home.export-head.html

However, all the links to CSS and JS are handled with clientLibs and therefore output relative URLS.  As the exported markup will end up on a different domain, I need to change these to Absolute URLs.

Has anyone got any experience configuring clientLibs to output absolute URLs, presumably using externalize Object?  I don't want to have to hardcode links to my resources.

Many Thanks,

Will

Comment: Lies your problem with the JS and CSS itself or with the referenced images in the CSS? For the later you can add the keyword absolute: in front of the url, then it doesn't get rewritten from the clientlib servlet that generates the combined files. E.g. background-image: url(absolute:/etc/designs/myproject/img/bg.gif);

Comment: CSS images are fine, as they are relative to the domain of the CSS file.  Its the CSS/<link href=""/> and the JS<script src=""/> that are the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you will want to do is implement a Sling Rewriter pipeline component. There's actually one which does something very similar to this the open source [ACS AEM Commons](http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/) project. The documentation as available on http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/static-reference-rewriter.html.

In short, a rewriter pipeline component receives the HTML of the page as a series of SAX events. It can emit *different* SAX events in order to modify the HTML before it is delivered. In this case, you want to rewrite link & script tags to make the URLs absolute. The Static Reference Rewriter is ACS AEM Commons might actually be usable for your use case as-is; if not the code could certainly be adapted to suit your needs.